# Can additivity of the Euler characteristic be interpreted in terms of the Poincaré–Hopf theorem?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Whenever there is a long exact sequence in homology induced by a short exact sequence of chain complexes one finds that the corresponding Euler characteristics are additive. For example, if $Y \subset X$ is a closed submanifold of a closed manifold $X$ (dim$X=n$, codim$Y=k$) with orientable normal bundle then the Leray sequence is the exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
\cdots \to H_i(X-Y) \to H_i(X) \to H_{i-k}(Y) \to H_{i-1}(X-Y) \to \cdots
\end{equation*} 
Thus, Euler characteristics of these spaces satisfy $\chi(X) = \chi(X-Y)+\chi(Y)$. How is this interpreted in terms of the Poincaré–Hopf theorem that says the Euler characteristic of a closed manifold $M$ is
\begin{equation*}
\sum_a \mbox{index}_{x_i}(v) = \chi(M)
\end{equation*} 
where the sum is over isolated zeroes of a vector field $v \in TM$? Can the intuitive argument that the sum of the right hand side decomposes into two parts (on and off $Y$) simply be used to prove additivity of the Euler characteristic in this case? It seems too simple to be true...

Comment: You should probably use homotopy invariance and extend Poincare theorem to manifolds with boundary. But this is not a research question, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Why is this not a research question?

Comment: Don't even know what to say. It looks like an algebraic topology homework. In fact, I *would* give a question like this as a homework.